# Disable Outlook Email Forwarding using ews

Tags: exchangewebservices, forward, disable

In Outlook there are options to disabled replying to and forwarding of emails.

My question is how can send disable mail using ews?

Answer (score 0):

VerbStream format is documented. See Glen's blog for an example: https://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2014/09/sending-noreply-noreplyall-noforward.html